# Silverlight EF Object Context Not generated in Web.cs file

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework-4

Here is what we have cooking, We created a DLL that houses our Entity Framework models.  We then created a seperate Silverlight Business Application solution.  Then the DLL housing the DAL was added into the project that would normally contain the EF Model.  We then added our Domain Service, the Object Contexts were available and the entities were in the list as they should have been.  Then after doing the compile and going into the generated file (***.Web.cs) that contained our proxy,  I found that the Entities themselves were there but not the Object Contexts they belong to.  Is there anyone out there with this same issue?